# How does flutter make this style of widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Click the action of appBar to expand a pop-up window below, and click action again to shrink the pop-up window.Or is there a plugin recommendation with such an effect?

[image]

Comment: using DropdownButton widget? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html

Answer (score 0):

If view of you is simple view, you can use simple popup, see [this](https://flutterrdart.com/flutter-popup-menu-button-example/) tutorial.

If view of you complex more, you have to custom it. You need create `Widget` container both menu and expand part, custom display like main page. Then show it as dialog.

```
showGeneralDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierColor: Colors.black12.withOpacity(0.6), // background color
  barrierDismissible: false, // should dialog be dismissed when tapped outside
  barrierLabel: "Dialog", // label for barrier
  transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 400), // how long it takes to popup dialog after button click
  pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) { // your widget implementation
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNodeCity);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: SizedBox.expand( // makes widget fullscreen
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
          
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```